# How to get file in WinRT from project path?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, directory

I want to add data files to my project. Those files will not change in the future. Where in project structure I can place them? I tried to put them into **Assets**, but sometimes they dissapear from there. Where should I put them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the file *and* the folder's properties (through visual studio) and check that "Build Action" is set to Content and "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy Always"

[image]

To read this file, then use:

```
var folder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("MyFolder");
var file = await folder.GetFileAsync("MyFile.txt");

if (file != null)
{
    var content = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
}
```

Source: [Windows 8: The right way to Read & Write Files in WinRT](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/06/windows-8-how-to-read-files-in-winrt.html)

Comment: I was set this. How I can take MyFile.txt from this folder (MyFolder) in code?

Comment: "not work" isn't enough to diagnose any problem. Please try describing what's wrong.

Comment: When run this line
`var folder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("MyFolder");`
With my parametr, thrown Exception Cannot find a file. Folder exist in project.

Comment: @LuckyChase Which folder did you put the file on?

Comment: In **GameData**,then I do this...
`var folder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("GameData");`

Comment: Debug your application, and check what the path of this line is: `var path = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path;`. Then manually navigate to that folder (through Windows Explorer) and tell me if you find the file there, or any subfolder.

Comment: line return path **D:\Words\Words\bin\Debug\AppX**
When I navigated to explorer my folder GameData is no exist in AppX, and some of folders from my project also. But all of them are exist in project.

Comment: Are you sure the `GameData` folder is marked with `Build Action: Content`?

Comment: Very big thanks. It's my inattention. You helped me!

Answer (score 2):

From your description its not clear whats wrong. You have to provide more details. But I think that putting files to Assets is a right way to do it and it should work. i dont see how they can disappear by themselves. 
Other option that might work for you is using ApplicationData class and methods and properties that are there. You can find it in Windows.Storage namespace. You can find more details about ApplicationData on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700361.aspx .

EDIT: Loading files from Assets can by done for example like this

```
var uri = new System.Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/YourFile.txt");
var file = Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
```

You can find more details on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh965322.aspx .

Comment: Tom, if I have folder in project with name, for example, Data, how I can take files in code from this folder?

Comment: just change Assets to whatever you want to as well as the name of the file. Or even put more folders to path if you need to.